# C++: String member alias in method

Tags: c++, string, reference, class-method, class-members

My constructor:

```
bnf::bnf(string encoded)
{
    this->encoded = encoded;
}
```

copies the string data to a member. (Or does it..?)

I will have a recursive decode method, but would like to avoid writing `this->encoded` all the time.

How can I validly and simply create an alias/reference to the member within a method?

Will this have overhead best avoided?

Comment: Down voters are so quick in stack overflow! It's impressive I must admit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass in a different named parameter. This is assuming that `encoded` is a private string member of your `bnf` class

```
bnf::bnf(string en)
{
    encoded = en;
}
```

In your other functions, you still don't need to write `this` if you don't want to:

```
void bnf::printCode(){
     cout << encoded << endl;
}
```

Assuming your class looks like this:

```
class bnf{
    public:
         bnf(string en};
         void printCode();
         //<some other functions>
    private:
         string encoded;
}
```

Comment: To be complete, you can use the same name if using initialize lists in constructors.

Comment: I know I can. It's not what I meant. I mean, in a different method, how can I `enc = this->encoded` **without** copying the data? And maintaining the member's state?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. What do you mean by `enc = this->encoded` without copying the data?

Comment: @stakSmashr I mean I just want `enc` to stand for the member, just to avoid writing `this` all the time :-). But when I think about it again, It's bad coding..

Comment: @Dror it's not bad coding, just style difference. There's nothing wrong with not using the `this` pointer. You can always refer to a private member variable of a class by itself without using `this`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49277/discussion-between-staksmashr-and-dror)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with what you're doing now. It's expressive, clear and correct. Don't try to ruin it.

If you're worried about "overhead" with using the `this` pointer, don't: it's already as efficient as it could possibly be. There is literally no way to make it faster.

If your question is slightly wrong and all you want to do is mention a member variable inside a member function, then:

```
struct MyClass
{
   int x;
   void myFunction();
};

void MyClass::myFunction()
{
   this->x = 4;
}
```

The function is equivalent to:

```
void MyClass::myFunction()
{
   x = 4;
}
```

Comment: It's not what I meant. But you are right with the first sentence I think. (Just stick with `this->encoded`)

Comment: The overhead I was talking about is regarding if I'd explicitly create a reference to it in the beginning of a recursive method.

Comment: @Dror: Not sure what you mean. Whether you create a reference or not, though, you have to access the member, and going through the `this` pointer is as good as any other method. If it can be optimised, your compiler will optimise it.